# Does AWS charge for lambda in sleep state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

For instance:

```
count = 0
        while True:
            try:
                if count == 5:
                    break
                snap = ec.create_snapshot(
                    VolumeId=vol_id,
                    Description=instance['InstanceId']
                )
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                sleep(180)
                count = count + 1
```

So If I have lot of instances and errors then it could be long time of running lambda. What could be alternative to put Lambda to sleep?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, taking a snapshot of a volume can take a decent amount of time.  And you're indicating you have many instances.  Can you perhaps describe more of what you're trying to do?  Lambda may not be the best solution.

Comment: why you have to sleep the thread? just run the lambda again after 180 sec using cloudwatch trigger for 5 consecutive times and if you want any data to be reused just save it in dynamodb or redis cache. This will save your time and money.

Comment: @stdunbar PS I will create new question then. I start to understand the point.

Comment: @VaisakhPS when snapshot fails due AWS needs to wait till better time to run. Ok lets make new question.

Comment: @stdunbar invite you to next [**guestion**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250680/back-up-multiple-ebs-on-aws-reasonable-approach)

Comment: @VaisakhPS  invite you to next [**guestion**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250680/back-up-multiple-ebs-on-aws-reasonable-approach)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you are still charged. Calling `sleep()` does not stop the execution environment. You pay for the duration of the execution environment, from the time the function is invoked until the time the function finishes executing (or until it reaches the configured timeout).

Answer (score 6):

My assumption is yes they do. AWS Lambda charges based on three factors

1. Allocated memory to function
2. Number of Executions
3. Compute duration

If you look at the definition of how duration is [calculated](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/).

> Duration is calculated from the time your code begins executing until
>   it returns or otherwise terminates, rounded up to the nearest 100ms.
>   The price depends on the amount of memory you allocate to your
>   function. You are charged $0.00001667 for every GB-second used.

AWS calculates charges from the time your code begins executing, to the point at which it returns/terminates.